# select query in codeigniter not working

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I want to write a query in codeigniter to fetch data from the database.

This is my Controller Function.

```
   public function add_qual_level()
   {

     $data = array('qual_level_title','qual_level_id'); 

     $record['result'] = $this->General_Model->select_record("qualification_level", $data);

 $this->load->view('admin/general/add_qual_level',$record);
   }
```

Note that "qualification_level" is the table name, qual_level_title and qual_level_id are columns.

This is my Model.

```
public function select_record($tbl, $data) 
{
$this->db->from($tbl);
$this->db->select($data);         
}
```

This is my View.

```
 <tbody>

 <?php
 foreach($result as $result_data) { ?>

<tr>
     <td><?=$result_data->qual_level_title;?></td>
     <td><?=$result_data->qual_level_id;?></td>

</tr>

<?php } ?>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
public function select_record($tbl, $data) 
{
    $this->db->select($data); /* or $this->db->select('qual_level_title','qual_level_id');*/
    $query = $this->db->get($tbl);  
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;     
}
```

**and In view**

```
<tr>
     <td><?=$result_data['qual_level_title'];?></td>
     <td><?=$result_data['qual_level_id'];?></td>
</tr>
```

---

**Check**

1. [Selecting Data in codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data)
2. [Result Arrays in codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-arrays)

Comment: did you check this ??

Answer (score 0):

Modify your model function as follow

```
public function select_record($tbl, $data) 
{
   $this->db->select($data); 
   return $this->db->get($tbl)->result();      
}
```